# css overflow hidden doesn't hide content behind padding?

Tags: html, css

I expect the text is chopped behind the padding-bottom but it didn't:

[image]

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div>html html html html html
</div>
```

Comment: The padding is not included because it is inside the div. Only stuff that is outside the div will be hidden.

Comment: use  box-sizing: border-box; properites 
(https://dev.to/tammibriggs/two2-ways-to-prevent-padding-from-causing-an-overflow-in-css-4ain)

you should visit this link

Comment: you want the why or a fix?

Comment: You are getting expected result according to you code

Comment: @TemaniAfif both?

Comment: @JasmeenMaradeeya tried but it doesn't work with css grid.